# Limit of the logarithm of values very close to one: $\frac{\ln(1-\epsilon_A^2)}{\ln(1-\epsilon_B^2)}$

Tags: limits, logarithms, limits-without-lhopital

I am thinking of a way to obtain an approximation I found in a paper I'm currently reading:

We need an approximation of the logarithm taken in a value very very close to 1. Lets say:

$A = \frac{\ln(1-\epsilon_A^2)}{\ln(1-\epsilon_B^2)}$

and we basically want to take the limit when $\epsilon_B\to 0.$

It happens that the paper claims that this is:  $ A \approx \frac{\epsilon_A^2}{\epsilon_B^2}$.

Does anybody have some idea of how this result popped up?

Any clue on logarithm rules or limits..

Thanks!

Comment: $\ln(1 + x) = x + O(x^2).$

Comment: Okay, thanks for your reply. That's a good start. So I guess that, the term $O(x^2)$ is negligible if $x$ is very very tiny? Do you have any source you can refer me to, so I can learn more about that stuff? Thanks again!

Comment: This is the first term of the Taylor series for the logarithm.

Comment: oh I see thanks. Will google it now.

Comment: This uses the standard *equivalence* (in the sense of Asymptotic Analysis) $\;\ln(1+u)\sim_0 u$.

Comment: I show in my answer that, if $0 < x < \frac12$ then $0 < -\ln(1-x)-x
\lt x^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that for $x\to 0$

$$\frac{\ln (1+x)}{x}\to 1\implies \ln (1+x)\sim x$$

indeed since for $x\to 0$

$$\left(1+x\right)^\frac1x\to e \implies \log (1+x)^\frac1x\to\log e=1$$

therefore in this case for $\epsilon_A,\epsilon_B \to 0$

$$A = \frac{\ln(1-\epsilon_A^2)}{\ln(1-\epsilon_B^2)}\sim \frac{\epsilon_A^2}{\epsilon_B^2}$$

Comment: Thanks for your reply, looks neat ! but, I'm wondering how you come up with the last line? I mean, what tells us we can conclude $A$ is approximately that ratio ?

Comment: @htennek2k if $ \epsilon_A,\epsilon_B$ are small (wrt 1) we have $\ln(1-\epsilon_A^2)\sim -\epsilon_A^2$ and $\ln(1-\epsilon_B^2)\sim -\epsilon_B^2$.

Answer (score 1):

$\ln(1-x)
=\int_1^{1-x}\dfrac{dt}{t}
$
so
$-\ln(1-x)
=-\int_1^{1-x}\dfrac{dt}{t}
=\int^1_{1-x}\dfrac{dt}{t}
=\int^0_{-x}\dfrac{dt}{1+t}
=\int_0^{x}\dfrac{dt}{1-t}
$
so
$-\ln(1-x)-x
=\int_0^{x}\dfrac{dt}{1-t}-x
=\int_0^{x}(\dfrac{1}{1-t}-1)dt
=\int_0^{x}\dfrac{t\,dt}{1-t}
$
so,
if $1 > x > 0$,
$-\ln(1-x)-x
\gt 0$
and
$-\ln(1-x)-x
\lt \int_0^{x}\dfrac{t\,dt}{1-x}
=\dfrac{x^2}{2(1-x)}
$.

In particular,
if $0 < x < \frac12$,
$0 < -\ln(1-x)-x
\lt x^2$.

Of course
the power series is
$-\ln(1-x)
= x+\dfrac{x^2}{2}+...
$.
We can get the
first two terms by
$\dfrac{x^2}{2(1-x)}
=\dfrac{x^2-x^3+x^3}{2(1-x)}
=\dfrac{x^2(1-x)+x^3}{2(1-x)}
=\dfrac{x^2}{2}+\dfrac{x^3}{2(1-x)}
$.

This can be readily extended
to get the full power series
for $\ln(1-x)$
using
$\dfrac{1-x^n}{1-x}
=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k
$
so that
$\dfrac{1}{1-x}
=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k
+\dfrac{x^n}{1-x}
$
and integrating.